# Multiplication in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So I have this code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function getCodeNameSpecsSize(data, type, dataToSet) {
        return data[3] + ", " + data[4] + ", " + data[5] + ", " + data[6];
    }

    function getTotalPrice(data, type, dataToSet) {
        return data[7] * data[9];
    }
    
    var table = $('#incoming_material').dataTable( {
        "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        "scrollY": 350,
        "scrollX": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "ajax": "Scripts/server-response-im.php",
        "aoColumns": [
                {"data": "1", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "2", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": getCodeNameSpecsSize, "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "7", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "8", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "9", "sClass": "align_center"},
                {"data": "10", "sClass": "align_center",
                 "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    var $currencyCell = $(nTd);
                    var commaValue = $currencyCell.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                    $currencyCell.text(commaValue);
                }
                },
                {"data": getTotalPrice, "sClass": "align_center",
                 "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    var $currencyCell = $(nTd);
                    var commaValue = $currencyCell.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                    $currencyCell.text(commaValue);
                }
                },
                {"data": "11", "sClass": "align_center"},
                { "mData": null , "sClass": "align_center",
                "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ) {
                    return '<a href="redirect_preview_po.php?c='+data[2]+'" target=_blank>Preview</a>';}
                }
            ],
        "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
        ],
        buttons: [
            'pageLength',
            'print',
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5',
            'colvis'
        ],
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I made **getCodeNameSpecsSize** function to work, but the **getTotalPrice** function is not working. The table show me *NaN* value instead of qty * unit_price.

```
QTY = data[7];
Unit Price = data[9];
```

Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the type of data[7] and data[9]. In case they are string type then multiplication may not work.

Try to use parseInt(data[7]) * parseInt(data[9]) and see if that works.

Comment: QTY and Unit Price are already BIGINT in my table, also I've tried your code return parseInt(data[7]) * parseInt(data[9]); it's not working. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to debug without any sample input data. Try adding a break point in the function or log to console to see whats going on.  Also temporarily comment out fnCreatedCell function and try isolating the issue.

Comment: My code is working now. My bad. After I re-checked everything, I get that unit_price = data[10]; not data[9]; So that's make the result not available or NaN. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a function to `data:`, but that's not what it expects. That option should point to a field in the data. If you want that column to display data calculated by the function, that's what `render:` is for.

As a note, you're mixing the pre-1.10 notation with the post-1.10 notation; for example, you're using `mRender` when you should be just using `render`. All of the [hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) can and should be replaced by the new notation.

Regardless of the above note, here's how you can get a column to render the data that is the result of passing `data[7]` and `data[8]` to the `getTotalPrice` function.

```
{"data": null, "sClass": "align_center",
    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
    var $currencyCell = $(nTd);
    var commaValue = $currencyCell.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    $currencyCell.text(commaValue);
    },
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return getTotalPrice(row);
    }
}
```

Note that the `data:` has been replaced with null. This is because the data is not in the original source but is instead calculated from other fields.
The other main change is the addition of the `render` option.

I'm not exactly sure what `fnCreatedCell` is supposed to be doing, but if this doesn't work, try commenting that out, since it may or may not interfere with the `render`.

Comment: My code is working now. My bad. After I re-checked everything, I get that unit_price = data[10]; not data[9]; So that's make the result not available or NaN. Thanks for the support.

Comment: By the way, the fncreatedCell function is to make rows became currency format (adding comas to the rows), I forge where I get that lol.

Answer (score 0):

My code is working now. My bad. After I re-checked everything, I get that unit_price = data[10]; not data[9]; So that's make the result not available or NaN. Thanks for the support, guys.